# Disable Office 365 2FA before period of leave without phone?

Tags: mobile, multi-factor

On enablement of 2FA in Office 365 Admin center, the only offered 2FA methods are

- Text message
- Call
- Notification in Authenticator app
- Passcode in Authenticator app

Obviously, all of them require me to have my mobile phone with me. But I want to be prepared for period of leave without the phone. Since there is no e-mail 2FA (to another e-mail account) method available, is my only option to temporarily disable the 2FA for my user?

For example for cases where I will get access to a computer to check my e-mails in browser.

Comment: Passcode authenticator apps don't need internet/mobile access - it's a protocol based on a pre-shared key (at time of setup) + current time.  I don't know if Office 365 supports it, but you may also be able to generate one-time-use passwords, too (you could use a recovery key for this purpose, but that's likely too powerful).  Otherwise, devices like a YubiKey can be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your MFA method, copy your Secret code to a paper in your wallet then use this Secret to generate OTP using browser-based OTP apps (whatever support HMAC OTP).

Comment: By "reset of MFA method" do you mean its removal? Also could you please provide an example of a browser-based OTP app which could be used?

Comment: Yeah, i typed the wrong term, as it would be **Add security info** at [this link](https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/securityInfo#/register?view=LandingPage) to update `another` factor authentication besides your existing phone apps but indeed you can **reset** by removing existing incase your phone left somewhere else. You can use this [crhome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/authenticator/bhghoamapcdpbohphigoooaddinpkbai)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check what you wrote and will attempt to configure that.  FYI, for the future, your answer will attract more votes if you improve it by using the [edit] link located below and include all the information directly in it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bring work with you. Set an autoresponder to instruct anyone sending to your account to resend to another person that's taking over your affairs while you're on leave.

Your Office 365 Admin can access your mailbox in case they ever needed something from your mailbox, and they can lock and force reset password your account in case you lost your phone. Accessing your account from a random computer without 2FA is very reckless. So take your phone with you so you can still use 2FA. If you worry that phone reception/mobile internet access is an issue, use Passcode in Authenticator app.

If you're the only Office 365 Admin in the company, you should set up another administrator.

Comment: Thank you and I see multi-user suggestion you are offering. I am not sure if I want to create and subscribe another user only due to security. The new subscription may make my costs 200% of current ones. Or maybe the user can be added even without Office 365 subscription? I did not think this way before... If you know, please reply. I'll also check what can be done.